# Como restar días a \DateTime('now')

Tags: php, objeto

Como puedo restar por ejemplo 4 días o cualquier cantidad de días a un objeto de tipo `\DateTime`en php?

Comment: Que has intentado ?, te sugiero leer este articulo : sindominio.net/ayuda/preguntas-inteligentes.html de como hacer buenas preguntas , porque te lo aseguro esta pregunta no tiene nada que ver con stackoverflow, te sugiero buscar en google :) y si no sabes como se crean las buenas preguntas aqui, te recomiendo leer el tour : es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Si lo pregunto aquí es porque no sé como se hacem es una pregunta de programación, y stackoverlow es una página para preguntas de programación. Como no sé de qué manera se hace no puedo poner un ejemplo de qué es lo que probado pues no sé por donde empezarlo. Además creo que la pregunta es bastante clara, tengo un objeto con una fecha de tipo `\DateTime` y necesito obtener la fecha de 4 días antes por ejemplo pueden ser 4 o pueden ser X...

Comment: @Palvo B. con una simple busqueda en google lo podrias encontrar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651263/subtract-1-day-with-php y https://benholland.me/tutorials/2012/03/11/adding-and-subtracting-dates-and-times-in-php.html,

Comment: @simon Es importante que tengamos una referencia en español de las preguntas más comunes, es el objetivo de stackoverflow. Por ejemplo yo he enlazado a la fuente de la respuesta, pero ahora si alguien busca en castellano este mismo problema no será necesario volver a formularla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Obtenido de esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901760/subtracting-days-months-or-years-from-date-using-php): puedes utilizar la función strtotime, para ahondar un poco más lo que está sucediendo es que el [formato relativo](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.formats.relative.php) está calculando el tiempo mediante el string que se le pasa como argumento. Luego el `string` lo conviertes a fecha con el tipo `date` corriente.

```
$time = strtotime('2001-11-14 -3 years -7 months -5 days');
echo $date = date("Y-m-d", $time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra solucion seria de esta manera:

```
$date = date('Y-m-j');
$newdate = strtotime ( '-6 hour' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $newdate );

echo $newdate;
```

[fuente](https://benholland.me/tutorials/2012/03/11/adding-and-subtracting-dates-and-times-in-php.html)